# Get percentage of distinct values with dependency on 2nd column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a survey that I sent out to people. One question asked their sex and another asked if they get headaches. I now have to results in an Excel file and I'm trying to analyze it.
But I'm having trouble to calculate a stat.

[image]

What I want is to calculate what percentage of people that experience headaches are men, and what percentage of those are women.

I know that  the concept is
`# people that are men AND experience headaches /`
`# of people that experience headaches`

How do I get those percentages?

Comment: I added a screenshot with an example if you don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal `countif` doesn't work with more than one column as dependency. Use `SUMPRODUCT` instead.

1. This formula will count all rows where *men* AND *headache* is true.

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100=1)*(B1:B100=1))
   ```

   Note that you can expand the formula to have a third or more dependencies if you wish »
   `...*(C1:C100=x)...`

   Example output = 2
2. To get the count of people with headaches, use `COUNTIF`, since here we only have one column to look for

   ```
   COUNTIF(B:B,1)
   ```

   Example output = 6
3. Now you just have to combine these two formulas

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100=1)*(B1:B100=1)) / COUNTIF(B:B,1)
   =SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100=2)*(B1:B100=1)) / COUNTIF(B:B,1)
   ```

   Example output = 2/6 = 0,333333 = 33,33 %
   Example output = 4/6 = 0,666667 = 66,67 %

   First formula is for men with headache, second for women with headache

---

There are some alternatives to the first formula `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100=1)*(B1:B100=1))` which will all give you the same result. Choose your favorite:

- `{=SUM(IF((A1:A100=1)*(B1:B100=1),1))}`
- `{=SUM((A1:A100=1)*(B1:B100=1))}`
- `{=SUM(N(A1:A100&B1:B100=1&1))}`
- `=COUNTIFS(A:A;1,B:B,1)` » not available in Excel 2003
- `{=SUM((A:A=1)*(B:B=1))}`  » not available in Excel 2003

Notice that most of them are [array formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) `{...}` which are entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[Source](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=273)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use an `AVERAGE` function like this

`=AVERAGE(IF(B2:B100=1,IF(A2:A100=1,1,0)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

When B2:B100 = 1 (headaches experienced) then 1 or 0 will be returned depending on whether they are men or women, averaging those gives you the correct percentage